# Active record query for a query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am working on a rails app which has three models 'request', 'service' and 'price'. Request and services have a has_many_through relationship, and service and price have a has_one-belongs-to relationship i.e a service has one price and price belongs to service.

The model with relationship

```
 class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :request_services
    has_many :services, through: :request_services
 end

 class RequestService < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :service
   belongs_to :request
 end

 class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :request_services
    has_many :requests, through: :request_services
    has_one :price
 end

 class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :service
 end
```

Now a user will create a new request which can have many services. So, I want to write a query to select the prices of the services that a user has selected in his request.

So far I have written this query,

1) To find the services in the request

```
 Request.find(1).services
```

2) After this I want to get the prices of selected services, so I am writing

```
 Request.find(1).services.prices
```

But this query is throwing error.

The error i am getting when running this query in rails console

Can anybody please help me in writing the query to fetch the prices of all the selected services

```
  Request Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  NoMethodError:   Service Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" INNER JOIN "request_services" ON "services"."id" = "request_services"."service_id" WHERE "request_services"."request_id" = ?  [["request_id", 1]]
 undefined method `prices' for #<Service::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f4ec4c41bb0>
```

Comment: Please share you model classes with the significant relation declarations and provide the full error message.

Comment: I have updated the question, added my models class and the error I am getting in rails console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can tackle it the other way around:

```
Price.joins(service: { request_services: :request}).where('requests.id = ?', request_id)
```

This gets all prices related to the request with the given id

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Request.find(1).services.price` (price is singular) since each service has only one price

Answer (score 0):

Essentially your query states: "For this request (1) give me the Price of each related Service"

But chaining doesn't work that way.  I'm unsure why you're using has_many-through called RequestService, but regardless, you have several options to get the price data for a request, a join, iterate-and-add-to-array, or the most simplistic add has-many-through on prices.

e.g.

### Iterate & Add to Array

```
prices = []
Request.find(1).services.each { |s| prices << s.price }
```

### Has Many Through

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :request_services
  has_many :services, through: :request_services
  has_many :prices, through: :services
 end
```

Which would let you do:

```
Request.find(1).prices
```

Comment: This method requires me to change my model relationships and I don't want to change my models just for sake of a query to work. 
Can I do it any other way? May be writing a proper sql query in rails active record ?

Comment: @LovishChoudhary there are always other options, but not knowing how or where you want to use it, it's difficult to pin down the right answer for the right situation.